# Numpy seed sometimes not working for dask function

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Seeding sometimes fails when running across dask distributed function calls. The desire is to pass in a seed value to a set of MC simulation trials which works most of the time; but, not always. The issue was boiled down to the following example:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import numpy as np

def get_rand4seed(seedx):
    np.random.seed(seedx)
    rand1 = np.random.rand(1)[0]
    return seedx, rand1

seedrange = 100
seed_ids = np.arange(0,seedrange).tolist()

client = Client()
a = client.map(get_rand4seed, seed_ids)
results = client.gather(a)
client.close()

for result in results:
    # take seed packed in result and calculate correct 1st random number
    np.random.seed(result[0])
    correct_result = np.random.rand(1)[0]

    # comparing with 1st random number calculated in parallelized func
    comparison = 'seed=%s, dask=%s, correct=%s' % (result[0], result[1], correct_result)
    if result[1] != correct_result:
        print('DIFF: %s' % comparison)
    else:
        pass
        #print(comparison)
```

Typically, 5 to 10% of the cases are incorrect and the error likelihood seems to be greater after the 10th or so item. And, sometimes all 100 items are correct. Example results:

```
DIFF: seed=10, dask=0.6503742417395917, correct=0.771320643266746
DIFF: seed=18, dask=0.5054533737348429, correct=0.6503742417395917
DIFF: seed=26, dask=0.038561680881409655, correct=0.30793495262497084
DIFF: seed=34, dask=0.780100460524675, correct=0.038561680881409655
DIFF: seed=69, dask=0.6063543377764754, correct=0.29624916167243354
DIFF: seed=77, dask=0.29624916167243354, correct=0.9191090317991818
DIFF: seed=85, dask=0.6575115686178157, correct=0.620373814553256
DIFF: seed=93, dask=0.3072410093435699, correct=0.6063543377764754
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6.9, dask 2.9.0

I cannot manage to run your code... Complains about not using `if __name__ == '__main__':` and then it gives me this

```
NameError: name 'results' is not defined
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

So instead, I looked at [dask.Bag](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag.html) and rewrote your code like this

```
import dask.bag as db
import numpy as np


def get_rand4seed(seedx):
    np.random.seed(seedx)
    rand1 = np.random.rand(1)[0]
    return seedx, rand1


seedrange = 100
b = db.from_sequence(np.arange(seedrange), npartitions=4)
results = b.map(get_rand4seed).compute()
for result in results:
    np.random.seed(result[0])
    correct_result = np.random.rand(1)[0]
    comparison = 'seed=%s, dask=%s, correct=%s' % (
        result[0], result[1], correct_result)
    if result[1] != correct_result:
        print('DIFF: %s' % comparison)
    else:
        pass
```

Code executes perfect and does not print anything, which I guess means that everything went right.

Comment: Not clear as to why using map/gather directly does not work; but, I do find that using the dask bag does results in the correct seeding.